# ServletModule : serve not finding jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, guice

I am trying to serve my login.jsp page but I always get page not found.

this is my **ConfigureServlet** method:

```
 @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {

    // load application settings
    AppSettings settings = AppSettings.get();

    bind(ObjectMapper.class).toProvider(ObjectMapperProvider.class);

    install(new JpaModule(jpaUnit, true, false));

    install(
        new ServletModule() {

          @Override
          protected void configureServlets() {
            // check for CORS requests earlier
            filter("*").through(CorsFilter.class);
            // pre-session tenant filter should be come before PersistFilter
            filter("*").through(PreSessionTenantFilter.class);
            // order is important, PersistFilter must come first
            filter("*").through(PersistFilter.class);
            filter("*").through(AppFilter.class);
            filter("*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);
            // pre-session tenant filter should be come after shiro filter
            filter("*").through(PostSessionTenantFilter.class);
          }
        });

    for (Module module : getModules()) {
      install(module);
    }

    filter("/js/*", NoCacheFilter.STATIC_URL_PATTERNS).through(NoCacheFilter.class);

    serve("/js/messages.js").with(I18nServlet.class);
    serve("/login.jsp");
}
```

my login page is under :
**src : main : webapp: login.jsp**

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether anything is being served at all, e.g by checking if static JavaScript files are accessible throught the browser.

If nothing is being served at all, you might want to check the logs for any deployment errors.

I'm not sure why you install `ServletModule` inside another `ServletModule`, this also might cause an error. The code could probably be simplified as follows:

```java
 @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {

    // load application settings
    AppSettings settings = AppSettings.get();

    bind(ObjectMapper.class).toProvider(ObjectMapperProvider.class);

    install(new JpaModule(jpaUnit, true, false));

    // check for CORS requests earlier
    filter("*").through(CorsFilter.class);
    // pre-session tenant filter should be come before PersistFilter
    filter("*").through(PreSessionTenantFilter.class);
    // order is important, PersistFilter must come first
    filter("*").through(PersistFilter.class);
    filter("*").through(AppFilter.class);
    filter("*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);
    // pre-session tenant filter should be come after shiro filter
    filter("*").through(PostSessionTenantFilter.class);

    for (Module module : getModules()) {
      install(module);
    }

    filter("/js/*", NoCacheFilter.STATIC_URL_PATTERNS).through(NoCacheFilter.class);

    serve("/js/messages.js").with(I18nServlet.class);
    serve("/login.jsp");
}
```